# Hardware and software setup for accessing and monitoring text messages on a phone connection

Tags: text, hardware, sms, hardware-interface

What hardware/software do I need to setup a machine that monitors incoming text ("SMS") messages on a phone connection? The software needs to be able to read the message, copy it to a database and then delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Three ideas:

- Use google voice instead of a cell phone, and your received SMS will arrive as email
- Obtain a cheap phone that features a serial port on the headset connection and can use AT commands (AT+CMGR or something like that) to receive SMS, connect this to a computer's serial port using a cable with level translation
- Use an Android phone and write an application which does this.